# Android Sound Recorder : android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-mediarecorder

I am using following intent to record the sound

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_RECORD_SOUND);
```

When the code returns to my program (in onActivityResult), the recording is not stored and log cat shows an error. This is only happening on Sony XPERIA with android 2.3 version. 
Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Below is the output from logcat:

```
01-02 21:43:17.837: E/Database(557): Error inserting album_id=8 title=2013-01-02 21:43:17 title_key=Q*?Q*?Q*?Q*?Q?Q*?Q*?Q?Q*?Q*?QQ*?Q*?QØQ*?Q*?QØQ*?Q*?Q mime_type=audio/3gpp _display_name=recording-379099974.3gpp date_modified=1357188193 date_added=1357188197 artist_id=8 is_music=0 _data=/mnt/sdcard/recording-379099974.3gpp
01-02 21:43:17.837: E/Database(557): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
01-02 21:43:17.837: E/Database(557):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
01-02 21:43:17.837: E/Database(557):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
01-02 21:43:17.837: E/Database(557):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1590)
01-02 21:43:17.837: E/Database(557):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1434)
01-02 21:43:17.837: E/Database(557):    at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertInternal(MediaProvider.java:1981)
01-02 21:43:17.837: E/Database(557):    at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insert(MediaProvider.java:1800)
01-02 21:43:17.837: E/Database(557):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:198)
01-02 21:43:17.837: E/Database(557):    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:146)
01-02 21:43:17.837: E/Database(557):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:324)
01-02 21:43:17.837: E/Database(557):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-02 21:43:18.057: E/WindowManager(1524): Activity com.android.soundrecorder.SoundRecorder has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2afe6e80 that was originally added here
01-02 21:43:18.057: E/WindowManager(1524): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.android.soundrecorder.SoundRecorder has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2afe6e80 that was originally added here
01-02 21:43:18.057: E/WindowManager(1524):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:267)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two fixes to this problem. I am sure there are others.

A.  Let the insert fail by catching an SQLiteException and doing something (or nothing) with it. This involves replacing the db.insert method call in step 2 above with db.insertOrThrow inside a try/catch block.

```
    try {
    db.insertOrThrow(UpdateServiceDBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, statusVals);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
     // do something with ex or nothing
     }
```

Simple but not too satisfying.

---

B.  In an IDE or on a device that supports API 8 or higher, instead of insertOrThrow, use insertWithOnConflict and explicitly specify a conflict resoultion schema.

This method call results in the conflicting rows being replaced.

```
     db.insertWithOnConflict(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, insertVals, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

The conflict can also be ignored:

```
     db.insertWithOnConflict(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, insertVals, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank for the response but unfortunately we do not have any control over as the exception is being thrown in the stock recorder app com.android.soundrecorder.SoundRecorder.